# Duda sobre Try-Catch anidados en Java

Tags: java, try-catch

esta es una pequeña duda sobre la lógica de tener un Try-Catch dentro de otro Try-Catch en Java, por ejemplo tendria algo como esto:

```
try{
 //codigo aqui
   try{
     //Aqui ocurre el error
   }catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.print(ex.getMessage() + "inner exception"); //Entra en este catch
   }

}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.print(ex.getMessage() + "outer exception");
}
```

Como ven puse el Try-Catch interno donde creo que dara el error, en el Try del Try-Catch principal, mi duda seria, si llega a dar un error en el Try-Catch interno, se imprimiría solo el mensaje del Catch interno? o tambien se imprimiria el mensaje del Catch exterior? o se imprimirian los dos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo se imprimiría el mensaje de "Inner exception", ya que la excepción queda sólo dentro de ese catch.  Si querés hacer que se "salte" al catch de afuera tenés que hacer un throw, algo así:

```
try{
 //codigo aqui
   try{
     //Aqui ocurre el error
   }catch(Exception ex){
     System.out.print(ex.getMessage() + "inner exception"); //Entra en este catch
     throw ex;
   }

}catch(Exception ex){
  System.out.print(ex.getMessage() + "outer exception");
}
```

¡Suerte!

Comment: osea que al aplicar algo como "throw ex" me lanzara el mensaje de la excepción, como si imprimiera "ex.getMessage()" y lo concatena a la excepción de afuera? o simplemente salta al catch exterior e imprime esa excepción?

Comment: Primero imprimiría el "inner exception" y después "outer exception", o sea, en el momento que hacés el throw envía la excepción al catch de afuera.

Comment: entendido, muchas gracias!